# Android Studio if statement with OR (||) Function

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am creating a mobile application that updates users with the current score and final score in a football match. I want the textview displaying the score to show only the current or final score.
I am having trouble with the if statement. I need one of the fields to contains something in order for a record to be created so I have:

```
if (!(et_currentgoals.getText().toString().isEmpty()) || !(et_finalgoals.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
}
```

Inside this if statement I was another that updates the textview with the correct values. So if the final number of goals was entered, the current goals are discarded. Would the best way be something like this:

```
if(!(et_finalgoals.getText().toString.isEmpty()){
tv_goals.setText(et_finalgoals.getText().toString();
}else{
tv_goals.setText(et_currentgoals.getText().toString();
}
```

Does this cover both scenarios or am I missing something?

Comment: If both are empty: Do you want to set the Text to empty or leave it untouched? Because if you want to clear it if both are empty you could fill an intermediate string with whatever currentGolas is, and overwrite that string only if finalgoals is not empty, then set that intermediate string.

Comment: @Fildor I do not want a record to be made if both are empty. That is what I am trying to do with the first if statement but I do not think I have the  || in the correct place

Answer (score 4):

Having that second `if` block inside the first will work, but there's a simpler way.

This single `if` will work.

```
if (!et_finalgoals.getText().toString.isEmpty()) {
    tv_goals.setText(et_finalgoals.getText().toString();
} else if (!et_currentgoals.getText().toString.isEmpty()) {
    tv_goals.setText(et_currentgoals.getText().toString();
}
```

In other words, these two blocks are equivalent

```
if (a || b) {
  if (a) {
    // a
  } else {
    // b
  }
}

if (a) {
  // a
} else if (b) {
  // b
}
```

If I'm understanding correctly, you are executing additional code inside of that first if statement, after setting the `tv_goals` text. To do that now, you can just check the text of `tv_goals`.

```
if (!tv_goals.getText().toString.isEmpty()) {
    // Do additional code
}
```

If this is the case, it ends up being the same amount of code as your original solution. You should just pick whichever way is more clear to you.

Comment: Would this still add a record if these fields are empty? That was what I was trying to achieve with the first if statement

Comment: What do you mean by add a record? What do you want it to be if both fields are empty?

Comment: I am using an SQLite database to store a number of different match results. If both fields are empty there should be no record. A user cannot add a match result without the score. My first if statement is checking if there is a score (current or final) and my second if statement is supposed to make sure the textview is updated correctly(if finalgoals exists, this should be used - not the currentgoals)

Comment: Gotcha. So my if statement will set the textview to finalgoals, if it's not empty, and otherwise, set it to currentgoals, if it's not empty. Thus, if both are empty, the textview will not change.